# How to compress a video into a specific size in kotlin

Tags: android-camera2, video-compression

i am implementing an android app in kotlin that records a 15 seconds video using camera2 API and i want to compress it into a specific size . How can i figure it out ?

Comment: By specific size, do you mean file size? I am not aware of any solution to compress a video file to a specific size. However, there are solutions to compress a video file to much smaller sizes(not specific size). I would try to use ffmpeg library for this. Using H.265 format would definitely help.

Comment: could you help me with the code  ressources ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a library like `ffmpeg`. An ffmpeg command like below would reduce the size significantly:

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx265 -crf 28 output.mp4`

where `input.mp4` is your source video file and `output.mp4` would be the target. It re-encodes your video file with `libx265` to have `H.265` format. You can read more about it here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28803/how-can-i-reduce-a-videos-size-with-ffmpeg

Of course, to be able to use ffmpeg in android, you need to add it to your project. The most complete implementation I have seen so far is:

https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/android

With the help of that library, you can execute aforementioned ffmpeg command.